# Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities dll not visible in reference list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am not able to add Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities dll. I have admin privileges & I am farm admin for web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This DLL can be found in 14 hive in ISAPI folder of SharePoint</strike>

Sorry for misunderstood. The namespace you are looing for is in the Micsrosoft.Sharepoint.dll. So what you need to do is to add reference to Microsfot.SharePoint.dll in your project and add using statement in the class to Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.aspx) description

This should be OK.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: DLL is there. Is there any link from where I can download it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference to Microsfot.Sharepoint.dll and then use

```
Using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities
```

if u still have a problem, find out that u are using a suitable reference type ( x 64 or x 86) and or good framework 3.0 +

Comment: try to change debug mode to "all CPU"